# A rigorous, formal real analysis multi-volume work by an Australian writer

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

Several years ago I saw at the library a textbook on Real Analysis by some Australian professor that was extraordinarily rigorous, formal and self-contained like nothing I'd seen before or since. It started from logic and set theory and worked its way up with painstaking detail and formal perfection.

I'd appreciate help in identifying the book. I believe it comprised of two volumes and was typeset in the horrid pre-latex, typewriter font. It had a yellow softcover. I believe it was published sometime between 1970-2000.

Comment: If you can remember a big enough *exact* sequence of words, that can be a tremendous help in finding the book.

Comment: @GitGud: Alas, I can't. It may or may not have been published by Springer.

Comment: Did it cover general measure theory as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:
http://www.amazon.fr/Formal-Background-Higher-Mathematics-Numbers/dp/038790431X/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8

Comment: Yes, I think this is it. I don't know why someone down voted your answer. Thank you! How did you do it? What did you search for?

Comment: The books look amazing. I couldn't spot any abuse of notation and I noticed several notation discussions. If someone types this properly, I'm buying it.

Comment: In fact I bought a book over analysis by C.H. Edwards, Jr,(which had a yellow cover) and this semester, I had a functional analysis class, and I mistakenly bought "functional analysis, theory and applications" (also with a yellow cover) from R.E. Edwards, without noticing it was not the same author. So I knew R.E. Edwards is australian, not that young so I just checked the books he wrote ;).